# Проблема с кодировкой при переносе сайта на другой хостинг

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, кодировка, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте, подскажите
Есть сайт, на котором все отображается нормально. Я скачал бэкап этого сайта вмесие с БД, ЦМС самописная, сами файлы имеют кодировку windows-1251, в мете прописана тоже кодировка windows-1251, БД имеет кодировку windows-1251, а таблицы utf-8, в htaccess нету ничего о кодировке. Начал переносить на свой хостинг. Создал БД с такой же кодировкой, как в оригинале, импортировал БД, перенес файлы, все норм, кроме кодировки, у меня на сайте выходят одни вопросики! Но в самой БД вопросиков нету, там отображается нормально текст. Пробовал уже разные варианты, по-разному экспортировал и импортировал БД, ничего не выходит.
Как избавиться от этих зловещих вопросиков?
Оригинальная БД
[image]
БД после импорта
[image]
Соединение с базой происходит таким образом:

```
function db_connect()
{
  static $ok;
  if ($ok == 1) return true;
  @$result = mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
  if (!$result) return false;
  if (!mysql_select_db('bd')) return false;
  $ok = 1;
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: В БД (phpmyadmin) в таблицах вопросики или же нормальный текст. Если в БД ок,то проблема в настройках сайта. КО.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh, да в БД в таблицах все нормально отображается без вопросиков

Comment: А почему у вас таблицы utf8_general_ci, а не cp1251_general_ci?

Comment: Раз ваш сайт работает в windows-1251, то и бекап у вас тоже в windows-1251 должен был быть. Проверьте редактором в какой кодировке файл бекапа. Если кодировка отличается от windows-1251, значит перекодируйте файл в windows-1251. Затем измените в файле бекапа кодировку таблиц `DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251_general_ci`. После этого восстанавливайте базу на новом месте из этого бекапа. Так же не забывайте после подключения к базе установить кодировку соединения в обязательном порядке.

Comment: @cheops не знаю, так было в оригинальной БД и я себя также сделал. На оригинальном сайте отображается все нормально.

Comment: При соединении делаете запрос `mysql_query('set names cp1251');` ?

Comment: @IvanBolnikh Такого запроса вроде нету, в посте выше я написал код подключения к БД

Comment: Хорошо бы изменить сопоставление и выполнить в скрипте инициализации `mysql_query('set names cp1251');`, как советуют выше. С 98% вероятностью проблемы исчезнут.

Comment: @Visman У меня файл базы данных .sql из бекапа в формате `utf-8`, а все файлы сайта в формате `windows 1251`. Попробую изменить кодировку в файле

Comment: Попробуйте `mysql_query('set names cp1251');` - должно помочь

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за помощь! Вопросики исчезли после того как я вставил `mysql_query('set names cp1251');` в коде после подключения к БД. Надеюсь когда обратно верну сайт на прежний хостинг (после редизайна) то вопросики не атакуют меня вновь :)

Answer (score 1):

В коде сайте прописать

```
$mysqli->set_charset("cp1251_general_ci");
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте в корне сайта на хостинге в файле .htaccess прописать кодировку винды где-нибудь после `RewriteEngine On`, например:

```
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
```